An equivalent condition of parallel mean curvature vector in normal bundle (in an orthonormal frame)
Question:
Let $f:M\rightarrow (\bar{M},\bar{g},\bar{\nabla})$ be an isometric immersion of Riemannian manifolds, let $\{e_1,\dots,e_m,e_{m+1},\dots, e_{m+p}\}$ be a (local) orthonormal frame, with its dual frame $\{\omega^1,\dots,\omega^{m+p}\}$, such that at any $p\in M$:
$$ T_pM=\mathrm{span}(e_1,\dots,e_m),\quad T^\perp_pM= \mathrm{span}(e_{m+1},\dots, e_{m+p}) $$
Show that the mean curvature vector field $H$ is parallel in the normal bundle, iff
$$ \sum_i h_{iil}^\alpha=0 \quad \forall \alpha,l$$
where $i,j,k,l\in \{1,\dots, m\}$, $\alpha,\beta\in \{m+1,\dots,m+p\}$, and:
$$ h_{ijk}^\alpha\omega^k =\mathrm{d}h_{ij}^\alpha -h_{kj}^\alpha \omega_i^k- h_{ik}^\alpha \omega_j^k+h_{ij}^\beta \omega_\beta^\alpha$$
My attempt:
$H$ is parallel in the normal bundle iff $\nabla_{e_l}^\perp H=0$, iff $\bar{\nabla}_{e_l} H\in \mathscr{X}(M)$. And we compute:
$$ \begin{aligned}
    \bar{\nabla}_{e_l} H &=  \sum_i \bar{\nabla}_{e_l} h_{ii}^\alpha e_\alpha\\
    &=\sum_i e_l( h_{ii}^\alpha) e_\alpha+\sum_i h_{ii}^\alpha \bar{\nabla}_{e_l}e_\alpha\\
    &=\sum_i e_l( h_{ii}^\alpha) e_\alpha+\sum_i h_{ii}^\alpha \nabla^\perp_{e_l}e_\alpha - \sum_i h_{ii}^\alpha A_\alpha(e_l)
  \end{aligned}$$
Therefore $\bar{\nabla}_{e_l} H\in \mathscr{X}(M)$ iff:
$$\begin{aligned}
    0 &= \sum_i e_l( h_{ii}^\alpha) e_\alpha+\sum_i h_{ii}^\alpha \nabla^\perp_{e_l}e_\alpha \\
    &= \left(\sum_i e_l( h_{ii}^\alpha)+\sum_i h_{ii}^\beta \omega_\beta^\alpha(e_l)\right) e_\alpha
  \end{aligned} $$
iff:
$$ \sum_i e_l( h_{ii}^\alpha)+\sum_i h_{ii}^\beta \omega_\beta^\alpha(e_l)=0 $$
By definition:
$$ h_{iil}^\alpha= e_l(h_{ii}^\alpha)- 2h_{ik}^\alpha \omega_i^k(e_l) +h_{ii}^\beta \omega_\beta^\alpha(e_l) $$
Therefore it suffices to show
$$ \sum_{i}h_{ik}^\alpha \omega_i^k(e_l)=0 $$
for any $\alpha$ and $l$.
But How to show this? I have been stuck for a long time. Or maybe the proposition is not true?
Sorry for the long read. Any hints, comments, solutions are highly appreciated. THANKS!

By the way, are there any recommended references related to formulas of Riemannian submanifolds ?

This is all tautology. The error in your calculations comes when you take the covariant derivative of $H$: You are treating $h^\alpha_{ii}$ as frame-independent functions rather than as components of a tensor.

@TedShifrin Thank you professor! But I still cannot see how to correct my computation, easy step seems plausible. Could you please explain it further? :)

As I suggested earlier, $\bar\nabla_{e_\ell}h^\alpha_{ii} = h^\alpha_{iil}$, by definition.

@TedShifrin Professor, sorry for my abrupt questions, but this is our definition in class: We know $B=h_{ij}^\alpha \omega^i\otimes \omega^j\otimes e_\alpha$, then we define:
$$ \tilde{\nabla} B:=h_{ijk}^\alpha \omega^k\otimes \omega^i\otimes \omega^j\otimes e_\alpha$$
By some computation we showed that:
$$ h_{ijk}^\alpha\omega^k =\mathrm{d}h_{ij}^\alpha -h_{kj}^\alpha \omega_i^k- h_{ik}^\alpha \omega_j^k+h_{ij}^\beta \omega_\beta^\alpha$$
So do you mean here the notation $h_{iil}$ is not consistent with the above? Or something else...?

I agree with all that. Your claim that $\bar\nabla_{e_l}h^\alpha_{ii}=e_l(h^\alpha_{ii})$ is what’s wrong.

It suddenly occurs to me that the last equality is obvious, since the summand is anti-symmetric w.r.t. i and k.
Therefore the above proof is reasonable.
(As for the discussion in the comments, I believe we are just using different symbols, everything is tautology.)
